# Average number of days between two date columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, average

I need to find the average number of days between `date_a` and `date_b`, across all rows.

| row | date_a | date_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2011-01-04 | 2014-01-04 |
| 2 | 2018-12-22 | 2021-11-19 |
| 3 | 2010-03-14 | 2011-01-01 |

The average number of days between `date_a` and `date_b` for this set is 817.3

There are around 10k rows in the table. Columns `date_a` and `date_b` are indexed.

What's the most efficient way of handling this, in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you can use `DATEDIFF()` function to calculate difference between two days and then `AVG()` function to get average of differences:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(date_b, date_a)) as average_days FROM table_name;
```

**UPDATE:**

One more way is to sum up all differences and then divide by count of all rows:

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(date_b, date_a))/COUNT(*) as average_days FROM table_name;
```